# After updating gradle to 8.2.1 problem with configuration cache occurs

Tags: android, gradle, mobile, android-gradle-plugin

After updating gradle to 8.2.1 problem with configuration cache occurs:

This is my error:

```
Configuration cache problems found in this build.

1 problem was found storing the configuration cache.
- Build file 'app/build.gradle.kts': external process started 'git rev-parse --verify --short HEAD'
  See https://docs.gradle.org/8.2.1/userguide/configuration_cache.html#config_cache:requirements:external_processes
```

this problem occurs with code:

```
val gitCommitHash = "git rev-parse --verify --short HEAD".runCommand(workingDir = rootDir)

then try to assign
versionNameSuffix = "-QA ($gitCommitHash)"
```

I saw solution with `gradle.properties` but it doesn't work.:

```
org.gradle.unsafe.configuration-cache=true
```

Answer (score 0):

I think configuration cache is not worth the trouble. Works for me in Android Studio but not on build server (where I really don't give a shit about the duration of a build).

I just deactivated it and it's running again.

gradle.properties:

```
org.gradle.configuration-cache=false
```